# The combined file is not being included in production

Tags: symfony, uglifyjs, uglifycss

I'm using **uglifyjs** and **uglifycss** with **symfony** to manage my asset.
I have a strange issue. 
Here is my configuration

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
     debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
     use_controller: false
     bundles:        [ ]
     filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        uglifyjs2:
                # the path to the uglifyjs executable
                bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs"
        uglifycss:
                bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglifycss/uglifycss"
```

And in my view

```
{% javascripts
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/global.js'
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/utilis/*.js'
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/utilis/*/*.js'
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/*.js'
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/*/*.js'
        filter='?uglifyjs2' %}

        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>

 {% endjavascripts %}
```

With this I expect to have only one file minified included in my page.
On my development machine (Windows 7, php 5.4, symfony 2.7) everything is working fine. 
But on production environment (debian 7, php5.4, symfony 2.7), all individual file is being included in the page.

```
<script src="/js/e434957_part_14_Store_1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/e434957_part_15_CrudPanel_2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/e434957_part_15_Form_3.js"></script>
<script src="/js/e434957_part_15_Grid_4.js"></script>
```

Can somebody help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you dump the assets, make sure you add `--env=prod` to the `assetic:dump` command.

You can also force files combining with `combine=true` parameter. But it should be set on true automatically on production env.

Comment: Yes I dump my asset **with --env=prod** option.  And this generate mimified and combined files. But the inclusion in the page is not correct. It seems my site is behaving as in dev mode.

Comment: You sure that your Kernel is on prod? It should be like this `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` in app.php

Comment: Yes I have checked it again and my app.php file is ok.

Comment: How about adding `combine=true` to `javascripts` tag?

Comment: Great!! adding `combine=true` solve the problem. Please Pawel can you add this as the answer to the question? I would also like to understand why this is not causing any problem on windows.

Comment: Added, but from what i know it should be set to true by default on prod env.